# Awk a space-separated file

Tags: bash, csv, awk

When I `awk` the following, an error is encountered.

```
awk -F '$1' "2.\ 2006-07\ and\ 2007-08\ ERB\ IN.csv"
```

Here is the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: 2.\ 2006-07\ and\ 2007-08\ ERB\ IN.csv
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ backslash not last character on line
awk: cmd. line:1: 2.\ 2006-07\ and\ 2007-08\ ERB\ IN.csv
awk: cmd. line:1:   ^ syntax error
```

Comment: The first argument to `awk` should be the script that will process the file contents.

Comment: why are you trying to escape the spaces?

Comment: Why are you using `$1` as the field separator of the file?

Comment: You don't need to escape spaces in a filename when you put the name in quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to print the first field in each line of the file, it should be:

```
awk '{print $1}' "2. 2006-07 and 2007-08 ERB IN.csv"
```

Since you left out the script argument to `awk`, it treated `"2.\ 2006-07\ and\ 2007-08\ ERB\ IN.csv"` as the script to execute. But that filename is not valid `awk` script syntax.